# Units in group rings in SAGE

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, group-rings, sage

Is there a recorded/known SAGE code to compute units in *integral* group rings for *finite abelian* groups ?

I would be happy with a code that only works for cyclic groups. I sort of know how to algorithmically compute it using cyclotomic rings, but I don't know SAGE at all, and also would expect this  to somehow have been done before.

Comment: I would use [gap](https://www.gap-system.org/) instead. [This](https://www.icts.res.in/sites/default/files/GARC2019-10-15-AndreasBachle.pdf) may help.

Comment: The paper ”Computing generators of the unit group of an integral abelian group ring” by Faccin, de Graaf and Plesken gives an algorithm which they implement in Magma.

Comment: @KasperAndersen : do you know where the magma implementation is documented ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Yes, I found the following on Willem de Graafs webpage https://degraaf.maths.unitn.it/units.html Unfortunately I havent had time to test it yet.....

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Another thing: The GAP programs in Chris Wuthrichs link only seem to be able to compute the units of $\mathbf{F}_p[G]$ where $G$ is a finite $p$-group (these are called modular group algebras). The Magma program can handle $\mathbf{Z}[G]$ for "small" $G$ (the program uses input on unit groups of $\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_n]$).